# RNN for Binary Classification

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking to perform a binary classification on each frame of a video. I have ground truth labels and the feature vectors for each frame of several videos, but am not sure how I could approach this as a time series problem to train an RNN.

How could I use the predictions on previous frames in a video to help inform future predictions? I think this could be accomplished with a one-to-one RNN, though I can't find any relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is quite similar to named-entity recognition task in NLP. In named-entity recognition you have a sequence of words and for each word you want to determine if a word is a named entity (say a person or company name) or not.

A many-to-many RNN architecture should be suitable for this task.
Please check for example the following article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-using-keras-bidirectional-lstm-28cd3f301f54

Instead of words you have video frames features, so you would need to replace the first Embedding layer with a Dense layer. Also in the above article N classes are used as labels and not just binary. So, as a started point you can try something like:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(16, activation="relu")))
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation="relu")))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model would take a sequence of video frame features as input and sequence of ground truth labels as output for each video.